# Use regex on list items to replace whole word

Tags: python, regex, replace

I have a large dataset `all_transcripts` with conversations and I have a small list  `gemeentes` containing names of different cities. In `all_transcripts`, I want to replace each instance in which the name of a city is given, by 'woonplaats' (Dutch for city).

To do so, I have the following code:

```
all_transcripts['filtered'] = all_transcripts['no_punc'].str.replace('|'.join(gemeentes),' woonplaats ')
```

However, this replaces each instance in which the word combination appears and not just whole words.

What I'm looking for is something like:

```
all_transcripts['filtered'] = all_transcripts['no_punc'].re.sub('|'r"\b{}\b".format(join(gemeentes)),' woonplaats ')
```

But this doesn't work.

As an example, I have:

```
all_transcripts['no_punc'] = ['i live in amsterdam', 'i come from haarlem', 'groningen is her favourite city']

gemeentes = ['amsterdam', 'rotterdam', 'den haag', 'haarlem', 'groningen']
```

The output that I want, after I run the code is as follows:

```
>>> ['i live in woonplaats', 'i come from woonplaats', 'woonplaats is her favourite city']
```

Before, I've worked with the '\b' option of regex. However, I don't know how to apply it here. I could run a for loop for each word in `gemeentes` and apply it to the whole dataset. But given its size (gemeentes has over 300 variables and all_transcripts over 2.5 million rows), this would be very computationally expensive and thus, I would like a similar approach as above in which I replace a string, using the OR operator.

Comment: Why not use a for loop? Your regex engine implement the same thing underneath. If you have so many `|` in the query, it's better to just use a for loop.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python regex list using list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19929605/python-regex-list-using-list)

Comment: It would be useful if you provided a sample `gemeentes` list and a desired result after the substitution. If I had to guess based on the information provided, you want `re.sub(r"\b({})\b".format('|'.join(gemeentes)),' woonplaats ')`.

Comment: @ZachWoods I edited my question to show you what I would like. Do you know how I could do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're close, but you'll want to change your `re.sub` call a little. Something like this should work:

```py
gemeentes = ['amsterdam', 'rotterdam', 'den haag', 'haarlem', 'groningen']
all_transcripts['filtered'] = [re.sub(r"\b({})\b".format("|".join(gemeentes)), "woonplaats", s) for s in all_transcripts['no_punc']]
```

#### Output

> all_transcripts['filtered'] = ['i live in woonplaats', 'i come from woonplaats', 'woonplaats is her favourite city']

As for performance, I'm not sure that you're going to get better speeds out of this over a traditional for-loop as you're still having to loop over the 25 million entries and apply the regex.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using pandas dataframe then you can use the following :

```
import pandas as pd

all_transcripts['filtered']= all_transcripts.replace([amsterdam', 'rotterdam', 'den haag', 'haarlem', 'groningen'], "woonplaats", regex=True)
```